# To check random variables i.i.d. or not

Tags: probability, distributions, independence

I have continuous random variables: $X_i;~i=1,\cdots,K$ which are i.i.d. and $Y_i;~i=1,\cdots,K$ which are i.i.d. However, $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent but not identical.

Now I have $Z_i=\min(X_i,Y_i);~i=1,\cdots,K$. Can I claim that $Z_i;~i=1,\cdots,K$ are i.i.d?

Comment: Yes you can claim that $Z_i$ are independent. This follows from the rules of independence, as long as $X_i,Y_j$ are also independent between each other.

Comment: are they identical?

Comment: Since the distribution of $(X_i,Y_i)$ determines the distribution of $\min(X_i,Y_i)$ when $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent, it is immediate that the $Z_i$ are identically distributed.

Comment: Yeah that is what i noticed too. Thanks @Alex and whuber for the clarifications.